# Growth mixture model (hlme) from lcmm R package failing to converge - continuous timepoints?

Tags: r, growth-model, growth-mixture-model

I am currently creating a naive model, where the outcome is a continuous biological variable, and the time to measurement is a continuous time variable, defined as the time since the individual received a diagnosis of Type 2 Diabetes.

The model is very simple:

```r
full_gmm <- gridsearch(rep = 100, maxiter = 10, minit = base_gmm, 
               hlme(fixed = var ~ time, mixture = ~ time, 
               subject = "id", ng = 2, data = df))
```

where the `base_gmm` refers to the ng = 1 model.

Currently, my model is failing to converge. The objective function remains at -1e-9 throughout all iterations of the model (using `gridsearch`), and the first co-efficient always remains at 0. `summary(gmm_model)$conv` returns `4`, suggesting the process was interrupted or unsuccessful. The data set is fairly large (~20,000 samples, median 20 observations each), and the median follow-up time is 9.7 years.

I have tried several different iterations of changing the time variable (days, different number of sig. figs., etc), but nothing has worked. If possible, it would be ideal to keep the time variable continuous, as the variable measured will change rapidly given 3-6 months, especially if medication is prescribed (which will be tested in more complete models later). however, I've seen using continuous time-scale models can cause issues with convergence in other SE posts.

Any ideas? I'm open to using Mplus/other R packages.